# How can I assign positives and negatives to a string?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create this code so that when variable J is present, it is a positive number, but if H is present, it is a negative number. Here is my code.

```
record = ['1J2H']
def robot_location(record: str):
    if J in record:
        sum()
    if H in record:
        ** I dont know how to subtract them** 
print(robot_location(record)
```

So if record = [1J2H] then the output should be ((+1)+(-2)) = -1 should be the output... how can I do that?? Somebody pls help explain this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over string inside list, check char by char and asume thats always length of string will be odd

```
record = ['1J2H']
def robot_location(record: str):
    total = 0
    aux_n = 0
    for a in record:
        if a.isnumeric():
            aux_n = int(a)
        else:
            if a == 'H':
                total = total + aux_n*-1
            else:
                total = total + aux_n
            aux_n = 0
    return total

print(robot_location(record[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a concise way to do this via a list comprehension:

```py
record = '1J2H'
nums = re.findall(r'\d+[JH]', record)  # ['1J', '2H']
output = sum([int(x[:-1]) if x[-1] == 'J' else -1*int(x[:-1]) for x in nums])
print(output)  # -1
```

Comment: you first need to `import re` tho

Comment: @Matiiss We typically don't exhaustively list libraries in our SO answers, where it is obvious which libraries are being used.  This is to avoid cluttering the answer with unneeded information.

Comment: that is first time I hear about that but I wouldn't consider that exactly unneeded information, especially because sometimes people (maybe simply out of habit) use aliases such as `import numpy as np` and then it may not be exactly clear which library may have been used

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is by using `iter` and converting the string into an iterable, that allows to use `next` which moves the iteration to the next item meaning that if one simply iterates over it it will get moved to the next item and then if one uses `next` it will return the current value where the "pointer"? is and move it to the next value so the next iteration with a for loop (list comprehension in this case) will get the next value, meaning that the loop will return only the numbers while `next` will return only the letters:

```py
lst = ['1J2H']


def robot_location(record: str):
    record = iter(record)
    numbers = [int(i) if next(record) == 'J' else -int(i) for i in record]
    return sum(numbers)


print(robot_location(lst[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modify a string like `s = '1J2H'` to `'1+2*-1+0'` and let Python evaluate it:

```
result = eval(s.replace('J', '+').replace('H', '*-1+') + '0')
```